# Then $K$ is a) compact b) not compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $K \subset C[0, 1]$ (with the usual sup-norm metric) be defined by
$$K = \bigg\{f \in C[0, 1]\mid \int_0^1 f(t) \, dt = 1 \text{ and } f(x) \geq 0 \text{ for all } x \in [0, 1]\bigg\}$$ Then $K$ is

a)  compact

b)  not compact

i thinks  this  will  compact  because  K is  closed and bounded by hein Borel thorem it is compact

is  My answer is correct or not ?

Comment: The Heine Borel theorem doesn’t apply; that only applies in $\mathbb R^n$ and similar spaces, not in $C[0,1]$. You probably want to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $K$ fails to be bounded and therefore fails to be compact.  Note for instance that the family of functions defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n & x \leq \frac 1n - \epsilon_n\\
\text{[linear function]}  & \frac 1n - \epsilon_n < x < \frac 1n + \epsilon_n\\
0 & x \geq \frac 1n + \epsilon_n
\end{cases}
$$
(where for each $n$, $\epsilon_n$ is chosen to be less than $1/n$)
is a subset of $K$ which is unbounded in sup-norm.

Comment: @omnomnomnom...if i take $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{2n}   <  \frac{1}{n}.$.in this  case  ur given function will not satisfied

Comment: I don't know what "ur given function will not satisfied" is supposed to mean

Comment: @omnom........i mean  linear function

Comment: "linear function" in this context means that the function is a "line", i.e. we have $f_n(x) = mx + b$ (for the correct choice of $m$ and $b$) when $x \in (1/n - \epsilon_n, 1/n + \epsilon_n)$.  Perhaps this wasn't clear

Comment: ohhh   i got  its  .......actually  some  misunderstanding in my mind   that is  i  was thinking   u take  $\frac {1}{n-\epsilon_n}$  but  it is $\frac{1} {n}    -  \epsilon_n$

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh That was a typo, I meant to write $1/n + \epsilon_n$.  Indeed, we do find that $\int f_n = 1$ (with $f_n$ as it is currently defined).

Comment: @Messififa Glad that's clear now.  I've made the answer a bit clearer anyway.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom....It looks nice....This one is the most natural example for this question....:)

Answer (score 2):

$K$ is not even bounded you may take another example say,

$f_n(x)=nx^{n-1} \forall n>1$. See $\|f_n\|_{\infty}=n \to \infty$